# Compile CouchDB from source on Ubuntu Lucid, automatically

Tags: javascript, couchdb, mozilla, spidermonkey

Mozilla SpiderMonkey is not provided anymore in Ubuntu Lucid as a standalone package. According to this [link](http://blog.syntaxvssemantics.com/2010/05/installing-couchdb-from-latest-guthub.html), you have to use the library provided with `xulrunner`, and say so to the CouchDB configure script:

```
./configure --with-js-lib=/usr/lib/xulrunner-devel-1.9.2.3/lib --with-js-include=/usr/lib/xulrunner-devel-1.9.2.3/include
```

This is fine, but I need to do this automatically. In my case this is not `1.9.2.3`, but `1.9.2.23`, and anyway this will change without notice in the future. I have an unattended script which installs CouchDB, and I would like to tweak it support lucid.

I can look for the library:

```
$ locate libmozjs.so
/usr/lib/xulrunner-1.9.2.23/libmozjs.so
```

And derive the `lib` and `include` directories from there. But this looks quite error prone (what it there are other `libmozjs.so` in the system, ...)

The ideal thing would be to ask `xulrunner` itself. Is it possible to query where its `lib` and `include` directories are? (`which xulrunner` gives me a chain of 5 (!) symbolic links which anyway do not lead to the `lib` and `include` directories)

Or better yet, is there a way to install the SpiderMonkey library in a standalone way in Lucid? (apart from compiling from source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**i386**
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/i386/libmozjs-dev/1.8.1.16+nobinonly-0ubuntu1

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/intrepid/i386/libmozjs0d/1.8.1.18+nobinonly.b308.cvs20090331t155113-0ubuntu0.8.10.1

**amd64**
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/amd64/libmozjs-dev/1.8.1.16+nobinonly-0ubuntu1

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/intrepid/amd64/libmozjs0d/1.8.1.18+nobinonly.b308.cvs20090331t155113-0ubuntu0.8.10.1

Here you are. You will also need libnspr4-dev.

Comment: I already had this in my script, and it is not working: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:launchpad/ppa ; sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install -y libmozjs-dev`. If I do a `sudo apt-cache search libmozjs` no results are produced.

Comment: These packages were taken off from Ubuntu Lucid and fortunately i've found them on Launchpad. I think apt-add-repository will give no result. The idea is to install them hand by hand so you should transform your script to this form: **dpkg -i %package.deb%**

Answer (score 0):

For reference, and according to the post by Dmitry, this is what I ended up doing:

```
# Install SpiderMonkey
if [ "$UBUNTU_VERSION" == "lucid" ] ; then
    wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/24586151/libmozjs0d_1.8.1.18%2Bnobinonly.b308.cvs20090331t155113-0ubuntu0.8.10.1_amd64.deb
    wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/17059687/libmozjs-dev_1.8.1.16%2Bnobinonly-0ubuntu1_all.deb
    sudo dpkg -i libmozjs0d_1.8.1.18+nobinonly.b308.cvs20090331t155113-0ubuntu0.8.10.1_amd64.deb
    sudo dpkg -i libmozjs-dev_1.8.1.16+nobinonly-0ubuntu1_all.deb
else
    sudo apt-get install -y libmozjs-dev
fi
```

Comment: I have to mention that libmozjs-dev also doesn't exist for Maverick and Natty.

Answer (score 0):

I use `pkg-config` for detecting libraries' paths, in a pretty similar fashion to your command line:

```
LDFLAGS="$(pkg-config mozilla-js --libs-only-L)" CFLAGS="$(pkg-config mozilla-js --cflags)" ./configure
```

works great for Lucid, not so great for newer distros, as mozilla-js doesn't exist there...